Issue with obtaining Device Context (HDC) of overlay window in C++
I'm developing an application in C++ that utilizes an overlay window to display visual information on the screen while another software is running. However, I'm experiencing a persistent issue when trying to obtain the Device Context (HDC) of the overlay window using the GetDC(hwndOverlay) function. The code seems to work correctly initially, but after a while, GetDC starts to fail repeatedly, resulting in an infinite loop of recreating the overlay window.
I have implemented a mechanism to close and recreate the overlay window when GetDC fails, but this doesn't seem to address the underlying issue. I have verified that the overlay window is being created correctly and that there are no other processes or threads accessing the HDC. Additionally, I have added debugging messages to identify the specific error code (GetLastError()), but it doesn't provide any clues about the cause of the problem.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
HMODULE hModuleGlobal;
DWORD overlayThreadId;
HANDLE overlayThreadHandle;
uintptr_t mainModule = NULL;
bool visuals = false;
HWND hwndOverlay;

void DoMagic() {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
    {
        visuals = !visuals;
        PrintConsoleInfo();
    }

    if (hwndOverlay) {
        HDC hdcOverlay = GetDC(hwndOverlay);
        if (hdcOverlay == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Error: unable to get overlay DC" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Closing overlay thread..." << std::endl;
            PostThreadMessage(overlayThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
            WaitForSingleObject(overlayThreadHandle, INFINITE);
            std::cout << "Destroying overlay window..." << std::endl;
            DestroyWindow(hwndOverlay);
            std::cout << "Recreating overlay window..." << std::endl;
            overlayThreadHandle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, OverlayThread, hModuleGlobal, 0, &overlayThreadId);
        }

        if (visuals) Visuals((uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"client.dll"), hdcOverlay);
    }

    if (!CheckIfIngame()) Sleep(1000);

    Sleep(10);
}

DWORD WINAPI OverlayThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    HMODULE hModule = (HMODULE)lpParam;
    hwndOverlay = CreateOverlayWindow(hModule);

    if (!hwndOverlay) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error creating overlay window", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    std::cout << "Overlay thread exiting..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void PrintConsoleInfo()
{
    system("cls");
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = { 0, 0 };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);

    std::cout << "[F1] Visuals: ";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, visuals ? 10 : 12);
    std::cout << (visuals ? "ON" : "OFF") << std::endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Press END to exit" << std::endl;
}

DWORD WINAPI MainFunc(HMODULE hModule) {
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);    

    hModuleGlobal = hModule;
    overlayThreadHandle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, OverlayThread, hModule, 0, &overlayThreadId);

    mainModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"client.dll");
    if (hModule)
    {
        PrintConsoleInfo();
        while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END) & 1) DoMagic();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Main module not found, press ENTER to exit..." << std::endl;
        getchar();
    }

    PostThreadMessage(overlayThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObject(overlayThreadHandle, INFINITE);

    fclose(f);
    FreeConsole();
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hModule, 0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainFunc, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

This is the output:
Error: unable to get overlay DC
Closing overlay thread...
Overlay thread exiting...
Destroying overlay window...
Recreating overlay window...
Error: unable to get overlay DC
Closing overlay thread...
Overlay thread exiting...
Destroying overlay window...
Recreating overlay window...
Error: unable to get overlay DC
Closing overlay thread...
Overlay thread exiting...
Destroying overlay window...
Recreating overlay window...

This is the CreateOverlayWindow() function code:
HWND CreateOverlayWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"OverlayClass";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes;
    securityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    securityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;
    securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    HWND hwndOverlay = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE, CLASS_NAME, L"Overlay",
        WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, &securityAttributes);

    //SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndOverlay, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndOverlay, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

    ShowWindow(hwndOverlay, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwndOverlay);

    return hwndOverlay;
}

Does anyone have any idea why GetDC is failing repeatedly and how I can address this issue?

You call it "utilizes an overlay window to display visual information on the screen while another software is running", I call it cheating in Counter-Strike. The "client.dll" string is a dead giveaway.

probably but you still don't know how to solve this

I find cheating in multiplayer games unethical. I added my comment to warn others that may share those ethics.

I don't want to cheat in multiplayer I want to learn new things, Assault Cube was first and now it's CS like almost everyone do... Anyways I'm asking about a specific question about overlay handle not how to cheat online

This question is already solved. As it seems that stackoverflow community doesn't like this kind of questions I will keep the solution for myself instead of sharing like I do normally in my other questions.
